# Overflow: auto on html,body breaks jQuery .animate scroll to top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button at the bottom of my webpage that when clicked scrolls back to the top of the page. This works perfectly and can be seen in my [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/330zyny7/).

I had another issue with a drawer in my site where the entire page kept jumping up when the drawer was opened - to solve this i needed to apply `overflow:auto;` to the `html,body` and that fixed the issue.

However in the process it stopped my back to top button from working. I wondered if anyone might be able to explain why or if there is an easy solution to this, I just can't figure it out?

To see my issue simply uncomment the `overflow:auto` in my demo CSS.

***UPDATE***

Thanks to a few suggestions below applying `overflow:auto` just to the `body` NOT `html` fixes the issue on everything except desktop Safari - anyone got any clue how to remedy this?

```
var offset = 300,
  scroll_top_duration = 700,
  $back_to_top = $('.top');

// Smooth scroll to top
$back_to_top.on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: 0,
    }, scroll_top_duration
  );
});
```

Comment: Does the issue persist if you remove `overflow: auto` and place it inside `.page-wrapper`?

Comment: can you just add `overflow:auto` to just the `body` and not the `html`? : http://jsfiddle.net/330zyny7/1/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion overflow:auto just on the body seems to have fixed on iOS but in my safari browser on desktop it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Ok so its a safari issue - your suggestion works just not in Safari, any ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that it doesn't like having overflow on the html element.
Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/330zyny7/2/

Moving the overflow to the body fixed it.

```js
var offset = 300,
scroll_top_duration = 700,
$back_to_top = $('.top');

// Smooth scroll to top
$back_to_top.on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert();
  $('body,html').animate(
{scrollTop: 0, }, 
scroll_top_duration
  );
});
```

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

body{
  overflow:auto; 
}

.page-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
}

h3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <p>Top - scroll to the bottom to click 'back to top'</p>
  <h3>
<a href="#" class="top">Back to top</a>
  </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, the fiddle doesn't seem to be working? I tried it in my site and for some reason it works on IOS but on desktop safari its not. :S

Comment: Ok so its a safari issue - your suggestion works just not in Safari, any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Not sure. It works in emulator. Oh wait you're saying regular desktop safari doesn't work... that's weird

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought I tried it in Chrome and its fine but Safari Desktop isn't working.