# overflow:auto on <body> breaks jQuery .animate scrollTop in Safari, Safari IOS & Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I have the following applied in my CSS:

```
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

The `overflow: auto;` is required for both `html` and `body` elements in order to prevent page/drawers from jumping when they are toggled open/closed.

For some reason having `overflow:auto;` on the `body` breaks the following JS for my Back to top button in Safari, Safari IOS & Chrome. Everything works fine in Firefox.

```
var offset = 300,
  scroll_top_duration = 700,
  $back_to_top = $('.top');

// Smooth scroll to top
$back_to_top.on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: 0,
    }, scroll_top_duration
  );
});
```

My question is not a duplicate as I have investigated further, found specifically where the issue lies and need help resolving this issue.

I've been stuck on this for ages and cannot think of a way around it so I'm open to any suggestions anyone might have?

Heres a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/330zyny7/5/) please test in all browsers to see my issue.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate of your own question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33902108/overflow-auto-on-html-body-breaks-jquery-animate-scroll-to-top

Comment: It's my own question that never got resolved we identified the issue together. I have experimented further so I need extra help.

Comment: Do you need the `width: 100%` for the `html, body`? That's what is causing the problem.

Comment: How do you mean? I just applied width:100%; to the html, body and that doesn't seem to have changed anything. Should I be removing anything?

Comment: Sorry, I meant, the `height: 100%` is what's causing the problem.

Comment: Ok so removing the height: 100%;  fixes the back to top however it breaks my sticky footer and my drawers jump up when they are closed. Does that mean I need to apply height 100%; to something else to solve that problem. I realise you can't see anything to help me but does anything spring to mind?

Comment: Ok, so the problem seems that if there's no scrollbar on the `body` element, the animation doesn't work..

Comment: The animation on back to top? yes I believe thats whats happening. However removing it causes problems elsewhere as its required for my sticky footer and height for drawers.

Comment: Any ideas on workarounds?